# Vuejs 2 impossible to interpolate attribute values

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, templates, es6-modules

```
 <th :class="{'c-' + column, active: sortKey == column}"
      v-for="column in getColumns()" @click="sortBy(column)">
            {{ column }}
 </th>
```

I get invalid expression: Unexpected token + in

but the syntax is supposed to be correct.

I tried like 20 other ways and everyone fails

Even if I put only `column` in there i get [Object object] instead of the actual column name

---

so, this doesn't work at all inside es6 template syntax.
It only works if I put the templates inside `<script>` tags in the index.html file

```
export default{

  template: `
    <div :class="[c-${column}]">
       ....
       <router-link :to="/list/${item.name}"> test </router-link>
       ....
    </div>
  `,

   created(){

   }

 }
```

I tried

```
${column}   - undefined variable
${$column}  - undefined variable
`${column}` - unexpected identifier
{{column}}  - invalid expression in vue
```

and other combinations and neither works inside the es6 template syntax.

so vuejs templates cannot be used with es6 modules and template syntax?

Comment: What is `getColumns()`?

Comment: It's a method that returns an array with column names (strings)...

Comment: the v-for  works. its the :class that doesn't work

Comment: @Alex have you tried: `c-${column}` and surrounded by backticks?

Comment: yes doesn't work either

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of the array that is returned?

Comment: You are using the object syntax, do `{ [\`c-${column\`]: true }` or use the array syntax `[\`c-${column}\`, { active: sortKey == column }]`

Comment: Looks like column is an object and you need to use `column.name` or something like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For HTML class bindings there are two syntax you can use:

[**Object syntax**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

```
<div :class="{ selected: isSelected }"></div>
```

The presence of the class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property used. The class binding is expecting the following type: `{ [key: string]: boolean }` or `Record<string, boolean>`.

When using a template string (backticks) as an object property name, you need to wrap it in square brackets.

ie:

```
<div :class="{ [`${dynamicClassName}`]: true }"></div>
```

[**Array syntax**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)

There is also the array syntax, which allows us to bind a list of classes.

```
<div :class="['selected', 'some-other-class']"></div>
```

We can use the object syntax in the array syntax like so:

```
<div :class="['some-class', { selected: isSelected }]"></div>
```

Using template strings:

```
<div :class="[`${dynamicClassName}`, { [`${dynamicClassName2}`]: isSelected }]"></div>
```

---

### Edit:

Try the following if you want to use a template literal:

```
template: `
    <div :class="'c-' + column">
       ....
       <router-link :to="'/list/' + item.name"> test </router-link>
       ....
    </div>
  `,
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly where the problem is because I can't see all of the code (Notably, the JS), but I'm just going to add a snippet that definitely works. The following code appears to do what you want (Or at least, what I think you want):

```js
function getColumns() {
 return ["a", "b" ,"c"];
}

function sortBy(column) {
 console.log("Do sorting stuff with " + column);
 app.sortKey = column;
}

app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
   getColumns,
   sortBy,
   sortKey: "a",
  }
 },
})
```

```css
.c-a {
  color: red;
}
.c-b {
  color: green;
}
.c-c {
  color: blue;
}
.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th v-for="column in getColumns()"  :class="{['c-' + column]: true, active: sortKey == column}"
      @click="sortBy(column)">
            {{ column }}
   </th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Note that if you want Vue to be reactive with `columns` (I.e., sense when the columns change), then *don't* pass in `getColumns`. Just pass in the columns array itself. Then use `app.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]` to set a new array of columns, and Vue will sense this. That's the way it's meant to be used. You can force update if you know `getColumns` is going to return something new, but this isn't proper Vue usage.

Vue is a well-built framework, so don't think there's anything out there it simply *can't* do. As long as you update using `app.something = newsomething`, it'll rerender the DOM efficiently and give you that really nice syntax to do it with.

PS: You probably don't need that `sortBy` function (I'm assuming it just sorts the rows of the table). If your `sortBy` is used only for presentation logic, it's missing the point. All of the presentation logic can be entirely within the Vue. You can see this in action using [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and [methods](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html):

```js
function getColumns() {
 return ["First", "Middle" ,"Last"];
}

data = [
 {
  "First": "Bernhard",
  "Middle": "G.F.",
  "Last": "Riemann",
 },
 {
  "First": "Leonhard",
  "Middle": "",
  "Last": "Euler",
 }, 
 {
  "First": "Karl",
  "Middle": "F.",
  "Last": "Gauss",
 },
];

app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  headerClass(column) {
    return {
      ['c-' + column.toLowerCase()]: true,
      active: this.sortKey == column
    };
   }
 },
 computed: {
  sortedData() {
   sortingBy = (x, y) => x[this.sortKey] > y[this.sortKey];
   return data.sort(sortingBy);
  },
 },
 data: {
  columns: getColumns(),
  sortKey: "First",
  data,
 },
})
```

```css
.c-first {
  color: red;
}
.c-middle {
  color: green;
}
.c-last {
  color: blue;
}
.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th v-for="column in columns" :class="headerClass(column)"
      @click="sortKey = column">
            {{ column }}
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="row in sortedData">
   <td v-for="column in columns">
    {{ row[column] }}
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Then, you can have all of the controller logic completely separated from presentation things like sorting the table. And, you don't have pollute any namespaces with `sortBy` (Using `sortBy` in the HTML means it has to be in the global namespace, which isn't going to work for a big project). I hope the above code shows how you can use VueJS to get full MVC separation.

As an added benefit, you don't have to presort the array using the default `sortKey`. As you've may have noticed, in my original code there is no initial "Do sorting stuff with a". The `computed` version handled the initial case automatically. Of course, this can just be done by calling `sortBy("a")` and probably pulling "a" into a `defaultKey` variable. The second option is still nicer.

---

This answer feels a lot more advertizy than I'd like, but "is vuejs just a waste of time?" is false in my opinion, and I thought it would be useful to explain why. That doesn't mean another frameworks like React isn't better, but VueJS is definitely a valid choice for presentation logic.

Comment: The console seems to hide the third entry for me. Try clicking `Expand snippet` to see all three data rows.

Answer (score 4):

When it accesses `obj['c-' + column]`, it gets undefined - which is falsy. You want it to be truthy, so give it an object like

`{
    'c-' + column: true,
    active: sortKey == column
}`

Leaving it falsy is just like having `sortKey != column`, which causes `active` to not appear in the classlist.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the template string in created method as shown below. It worked. I used some dummy values for demo.

```js
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      template: ``,
      column: "hare",
      item: {name: "krishna"},
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.template = `
      <div :class="[c-${this.column}]">
        ....
        <router-link :to="/list/${this.item.name}"> test </router-link>
        ....
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot of browser showing the result of template]