# Adding two computed class properties on a :class="{{}} {{}}" in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I'm pretty new to the Vue world and was curious if I'm able to apply 2 computed properties to a :class.
I've tried giving a space to each prop `:class="{{prop1}} {{prop2}}"`
but on reload the content will all disappear because something seems to be wrong.

Does anybody know if this is possible or if its even a good to do things this way?

***Backstory***

Im creating an input that will have the `:class="{{showWhenButtonClicked}}"` and another to give it a green input or a red input classname when the email is not valid.

If there are any details that I'm missing or a better way let me know. Thanks!!

```
computed: {
  validateEmail() {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(this.emailTo).toLowerCase())
  },
  showEmailInput() {
    return this.sendEmail ? 'hide-show-option' : 'hide-option-input'
  },
  displayEmailError() {
    return this.validateEmail() ? "valid-input" : "not-valid-input"
  }
},

<input :class="{{showEmailInput}} {{displayEmailError}}" placeholder="Enter Email..." v-model="emailTo" @blur="{{validateEmail}}" type="email">
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708313/4305494) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) to apply a list of classes:

`<input :class="[showEmailInput, displayEmailError]"/>`

Comment: Thanks Nick G & @Mubashar Ahmed Hassan Both of these answers helped and worked! For some reason I thought computed props could only be used within the {{double curls}}

Comment: @Pwntastic nope, any variable in your component (data, computed, props, etc.) can be used in the template without curly braces, so long as you're inside of an attribute with `v-bind` (Like `:class="someVariable"`)

Comment: If you are trying to render the text inside of a div like: `<div>{{someVariable}}</div>`, then you do need the mustache syntax

Comment: oh perfect! this helps a ton! Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 3):

Nick's answer is the best one so far. But you can also store the class in a computed variable, which I think cleans up the code:

```
  classList({ sendEmail, validateEmail }) {
    return [
      sendEmail ? 'hide-show-option' : 'hide-option-input',
      validateEmail ? "valid-input" : "not-valid-input"
    ]
  }
```

OR you can return an object instead, but in this case it's not as succinct as the array

```
  classObject({ sendEmail, validateEmail }) {
    return {
      'hide-show-option': sendEmail, 
      'hide-option-input': !sendEmail,
      'valid-input': validateEmail,
      'not-valid-input': !validateEmail
    }
  }
```

When you start to integrate more complex logic in classes, the two options above will make even more sense.

Comment: This is gold! I really like how much easier it is to read too instead of having multiple Comp Props. I really appreciate all the advice!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
:class="prop1 + ' ' + prop2"
```